# select rows in laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two tables `request` and `status_tracker`.`request` table has `request_id,approver_id ,status_id` fields and `status_tracker` has `request_id,status_before,changed_by,status_after` fields.Every request is reviewed and status is changed to 17/20.I want to fetch the record which is reviewed(status=17) and approver_id =1866 in asset_request table and fetch the  record which is  `changed_by`  '1877' in  status_tracker table.

I want to get the records 001(status.tracker.changed_by='1866'),
002(approver_id=1866 and status_tracker.status_after='17'),
004((status.tracker.changed_by='1866')).

```
request table 
request_id approver_id  status_id requestor
001          11              18    301
002          1866            17    113
003          115             17    159
004          112             19    163
005          1866            1     172
006          1866            20    172  

status_tracker
request_id  status_before   status_after changed_by
  001           null           1            301
  001            1             17          1687
  001            17             8          1724
  001            8             18          1866   
  002           null            2           113
  002            2             17          1687 
  003            null           1           159
  003            1             17          1687
  004            null          1            163
  004            1             17          1687
  004            17             8          1724
  004            8              19         1866     
  005            null           1          172 
  006            null           1          172
  006            1              20         1687
```

I have tried as

```
$users = DB::table('asset_status_tracker')
->leftJoin('asset_request', 'asset_status_tracker.request_id', '=','asset_request.request_id')
->where('asset_status_tracker.status_before','!=',null)
->orwhere('asset_status_tracker.changed_by','=',$approver_id)
->orwhere('asset_request.approver_id','=',$approver_id)
->where('asset_status_tracker.status_after','=','17')->get();
```

now I get all reviewed records 001,002,003,004,005.What I did worng

Comment: Your logic is not clear to me (and maybe not even to you).  Please give the exact rules for why `001`, `002`, and `004` should appear in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$users = DB::table('asset_status_tracker')
    ->leftJoin('asset_request', 'asset_status_tracker.request_id', '=','asset_request.request_id')
    ->where('asset_status_tracker.status_before','!=',null)
    ->orwhere(function($query) use ($approver_id) {$query->where('asset_status_tracker.changed_by','=',$approver_id)
    ->where('asset_request.approver_id','=',$approver_id);})
    ->where('asset_status_tracker.status_after','=','17')->get();
```

Comment: I posted answer on mobile. Sorry for style.

Answer (score 0):

Put your both Orwhere in one function

```
->orwhere(function($subQ) use ($approver_id) {
    $subQ->where('asset_status_tracker.changed_by','=',$approver_id)
    ->orwhere('asset_request.approver_id','=',$approver_id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$users = DB::table('asset_status_tracker')
->leftjoin('asset_request',function($join)
                           {
                                 $join->on('asset_status_tracker.request_id', '=','asset_request.request_id')
                                        ->where('asset_request.approver_id','=',$approver_id)
                                         ->where('asset_status_tracker.status_after','=','17');
                           })
->where('asset_status_tracker.status_before','!=',null)
->orwhere('asset_status_tracker.changed_by','=',$approver_id)->get();
```